# Why am I getting duplicate records for this query? I am performing a Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sapb1

I am entering the following query below and getting duplicate values.  I thought if I did a Left Outer Join that it wouldn't do that.  I want `T0.` data for 2 of the 3 columns.  The one column that I want `T1.` data is for the related customer name to the customer code.  But it seems to want to populate the record twice.

Here is the code that I am attempting to use:

```
SELECT  T0.CardCode
        ,T1.CardName
        ,T0.State

FROM CRD1 T0 LEFT OUTER JOIN OCRD T1 ON T0.CardCode=T1.CardCode
```

Comment: You clearly do not understand what `left outer join` does.  You should edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: You are correct.  That is why I am asking for some help.  I tried to post an image but I have not gained the reputation status on here to do so.  The current results I am getting with the query are 3 columns called [CardCode] | [CardName] | [State].  I am getting 2 rows for every customer.  So I will see Company ABC with [State] 'AZ' on rows 1 & 2.  The same record just populated 2 times.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using distinct keyword.

```
SELECT distinct  
    T0.CardCode
    ,T1.CardName
    ,T0.State

FROM CRD1 T0 LEFT OUTER JOIN OCRD T1 ON T0.CardCode=T1.CardCode
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh.  Worked perfectly!

Comment: Bad advice, even when it is working - using 'distinct' usually masks down serious problems with data and/or query design.

Comment: When you say "Masks down", what top of problems is hiding from the user?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means you have multiple matches on the join predicate in the related table. The left outer join ensures you keep all rows from the left table regardless of match or not, but doesn't prevent multiple matches if they happen to exist. Example:

```
with _left (id)
as (
    select 3 union all
    select 4 union all
    select 5 
)

,_right(id)
as (
    select 3 union all
    select 3 
)

select *
from _left l
left join _right r on l.id = r.id
```

Result:

```
id  id
3   3
3   3
4   NULL
5   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword distinct in your select query.Then you will get only single records in the output grid.

Thanks.